# Jest fails when imports files from repository using import/export default syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs, babeljs, commonjs

I'm using some files from another repository which is written in es6 syntax.

The current project also is written with es6 syntax, but Babel is configured so tests don't fail on the imports.
but when it tries to import file from that repository it fails. 
When I rewrite es6 imports and exports into CommonJS require syntax tests does not fail.

Do I need some additional configuration of Jest or Babel?

Comment: Do you have a jest config file? I know that with karma testing, there is a karma.conf.js file, that tells karma to essentially use your webpack file and with that, babel.

Comment: @Brett East yeah, I have Babel and Jest configs. Jest works properly if tests don't try to import files from that repository.

Comment: I don't know enough about the jest setup, so I can only try and help based on my karma knowledge, although I did find this - https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started#using-babel - do you have these dependencies installed?

Comment: @Brett East yep, everything is installed and set up

Comment: In that case, I don't think I can help

Comment: What is your current Babel configuration file setup?

Comment: just clarifying before I answer: you are importing a module from `node_modules` that uses ES6 syntax, is that right?

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors yes, correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just need some additional configuration of `Jest`.

By default `Jest` does not transform anything in `node_modules`.

That behavior is controlled by the configuration option [`transformIgnorePatterns`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#transformignorepatterns-array-string) which defaults to`["/node_modules/"]`.

If there is code within `node_modules` that needs to be transformed then you can whitelist those modules by modifying `transformIgnorePatterns` in your `Jest` config:

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "node_modules/(?!(first-module-to-transform|second-module-to-transform)/)"
]
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. As I understand, if I would set `transformIgnorePatterns` to empty array it has to work? Because it also doesn't work. Probably I missed some additional configuration.

Comment: so finally I've worked it out. Your answer helped me, but after I moved my babel config from `.babelrc`  into `babel.config.js`.